# iPhone - Button creates Action View, how to push class properties?

Tags: uitableview, ios4, uibutton, parameter-passing, uialertview

Hey guys, just had a question about UIAlertViews.
I have a button within a cell, and I wish to push an object's data into the UIAlertView body section. Right now I have this:

```
- (void)locationButton:(id)selector{
    NSString *addressBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[testList     objectAtIndex:selectedCellIndexPath.row] address]];
    UIAlertView *addressView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                message:addressBody
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Show on Map", nil];
    [addressView show];
    [addressView release];
}
```

Within the viewDidLoad, I initialized my Conference class like

```
testList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Conference *conf1 = [[Conference alloc] initWithConferenceId:110];
Conference *conf2 = [[Conference alloc] initWithConferenceId:130];
[testList addObject:conf1];
[testList addObject:conf2];
```

however when the button is pushed, the alert view does not display and it will eventually crash with

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Conference address]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e273a0'"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Conference` class, there is no `address` method implemented.

This could just be a spelling mistake in the implementation. But it would be more helpful if you posted code in your Conference class.

Comment: Oops! I realized I tried to call something that does not exist ;)